# Javascript ++ Operator Priority

Tags: javascript, recursion, operators

I'm wondering what the priority of the `++` operator is when being called through a recursive function like so.

```
var count = 0;
function recur(x){
    if(x == 10)
        return x;
    else
        return recur(x++);
}

recur(count);
```

In the code, when `return recur(x++)` is being called, is x passing to the `recur` method as x, or as x+1? And what is the difference between `x++` and `++x`?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of asking someone what value is passed, why not see for yourself what is passed? `console.log(x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `return recur(x++)`, it will return the first value and then will increase. `return recur(++x)` does exactly the opposite, value first increases and then returns. This is the difference `x++`, first run the command after increments, and `++x` first increases then run the command.

Answer (score 1):

Well the difference between x++ vr. ++x is:

```
var x = 5, y = 5;

console.log(++x); // outputs 6
console.log(x); // outputs 6

console.log(y++); // outputs 5
console.log(y); // outputs 6
```

So for ++x increments the variable inmediately.